# DTOs that are too heavy to be shared

Tags: c#, design-patterns, poco, dto

I have a domain entity currently within my application which exposes functionality via wcf and restful api - where the properties are decorated with various attributes - like SwaggerWCF for example, and some validation rules like [Mandatory].

Now this is fine, however I am now working on a client library to faciliate consuming the services. The typical pattern I follow here is to break the DTOs out into a separate nuget package which is then used by the service and the client.

However these DTos are heavy - hell they probably aren't arent even dtos.

How can I expose my lovely POCOS as Dtos and then layer up the extra stuff on the service side?

I can only see duplication on the road ahead....

Comment: Not a full answer in and of itself, but the issues you're faced with is the main drawback when using attributes. They are effectively logic which attaches to properties, which is an issue when you want to have data-only classes. EF gets around this by also giving you the option of using Fluent API which isn't connected to the entity class itself. However, I'm not sure if your attributes have alternative options available.

Comment: This would be a nice suggestion. If this were the case then this extra functionality could be layer on after the fact on the server side. However this would not make it clear on the client side that behaviour is going to be added. The route I went was to create an incredibly light weight attribute that is used by the POCOs this enables the client to bring in very little but atleast you know what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

DTOs which are usually the smaller bits that get transferred usually serve 2 purposes, to a) make the data smaller for transfer and b) to allow some abstraction from the inner workings to prevent exposing everything if needed.

If a) is not a concern since they would be large, b) is still useful in hiding some properties etc down the road, so creating almost duplicate DTOs is probably ok, and can be managed using some kind of auto mapping.

Having DTOs separates these concerns and if you need to provide a client library these can be more easily extracted into a separate package.